# Item selection in spinner in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, spinner, adapter

I have spinner with default text. The default text is not available in array which is using for display spinner items. For that I am using custom array adapter following.

For example I am displaying default text is 14:13 but in my array the text is 14:15. I want to do setSelection for this item(14:15). What can I do for this?

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

            Context context;
            String[] objects;
            String firstElement;
            boolean isFirstTime;

            public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects, String defaultText) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
                this.context = context;
                this.objects = objects;
                this.isFirstTime = true;
                setDefaultText(defaultText);
            }

            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                if(isFirstTime) {
                    objects[0] = firstElement;
                    isFirstTime = false;
                }
//              ((TextView) convertView).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
            }

            public void setDefaultText(String defaultText) {
                this.firstElement = objects[0];
                objects[0] = defaultText;
            }

            public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.time_item, parent, false);
                TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_time);
                label.setText(objects[position]);
                return row;
            }


            }
```

[image: spinner image]

The following image tells the exact requirement. If you can observe that first when we come to actvity the spinner shows the default text "10:39", but in the spinner arraylist we are having the values 10:37 and 10:50. So I want to display it as nearby value.

Now I am displaying default value and when we tap it popup the spinner values working perfectly. But what I want is when I tap the spinner it automatically scroll to 10:37 and shows it will be selected item.

Comment: I got it working when i give the variable position which is available in arraylist to adapter class.For selection used for setSelection(position).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this codes for spinner adapter.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.your_spinner);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(YourActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_item, array_spinner);
//array_spinner is your array to displayed on spinner selection

spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setPrompt("Choosed item");
spinner.setSelection(int position); //position of item in your array_spinner
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: hi BatuhanC,i want to set default text and when u tap the spinner only i have to scrolldown automatically for particular item in the dropdown.so it will be the selected item.i done defaulttext by using above custom adapter.